# how to print string to html

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-socketio

I want to make live db updates and display them in html.

I'm using a Jinja template with this code snippet, but it doesn't work.

```
{{% for msg in dbmsg %}} {{ msg }}
```

This is the code I'm using to send the message.

```
class RandomThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.delay = 1
        super(RandomThread, self).__init__()

    def randomNumberGenerator(self):
        while not thread_stop_event.isSet():
            mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM pydb.live')
            dbmsg = mycursor.fetchall()
            mydb.commit()
            socketio.emit('newreuslt', {'result': dbmsg}, namespace='/test')
            sleep(self.delay)

    def run(self):
        self.randomNumberGenerator()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly get flask-socketio messages in a Jinja template.  I suggest you look at the [flask-socketio examples](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to see how to include the proper Javascript dependencies (socketio) to make this work.